# Can't recieve incoming mail with Mailgun

Tags: api, email, smtp, mailgun

I'm trying to set up inbound mail with mailgun.  I want to receive email at support@mydomain.com. (changed for privacy)

- All Mailgun's DNS checks pass.
- I have a route set up.  The expression is `match_recipient("support@mydomain.com")` and the action is `forward("me@gmail.com")`
- When I use the route testing tool it correctly matches my route.

But when I send email in real life to support@mydomain.com, I get a failure notice.  The error message is:

```
Your message cannot be delivered to the following recipients: 

Recipient address: support@mydomain.com 
Reason: Remote SMTP server has rejected address 
Diagnostic code: smtp;550 5.7.1 Relaying denied 
Remote system: dns;mxb.mailgun.org (TCP|17.172.80.96|58312|52.5.239.85|25) (ak47 ESMTP ready)
```

What step am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is over a year old, but since I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out, I will share my solution:
My mailgun account wasn't verified. I saw someone suggest this but I figured they just meant that I had to verify the address I was forwarding to.  Nope, when I logged it today I saw a banner at the top saying click here to resend your verification email.  I did that, it went through a text message verification process, and all immediately started working!

Comment: You just saved at least four hours of my life, their confirmation email got sent to my spam folder and I never would have looked for it.

Comment: Please check whether you have previously configured an additional subdomain like `mail.yourdomain.com` along with `yourdomain.com`. Then the same issue could come up. Then you have to delete one to proceed.