# Mail routing with mailgun

Tags: email, routes, mailgun

I'm setting mailgun route to xx@me.com to forward an email to a server at http://xxx:7000/reply. 
I tested already the email route and it's fine as well as the server is up both in browser and using curl. However sending an email to xx@me.com still nothing happens.

There is already a similar question but nobody answered: 
[Can't recieve incoming mail with Mailgun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293007/cant-recieve-incoming-mail-with-mailgun)

Answer (score 13):

There are a few requirements for handling incoming emails with Mailgun.

- Your account must be verified (email/SMS message)
- The domain or subdomain must be added to the account.
- SPF & DKIM must be verified and have MX records configured with Mailgun's values. [Details for DNS record information](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain)
- Route filters configured with the recipient domain or subdomain matching. (Example: Domain "bar.com" is added to the account. The expression can match_recipient("foo@bar.com"). If a subdomain is added, then it will need to match the subdomain, e.g. match_recipient("foo@mg.bar.com"))

The error from the linked question would be due to one of the above requirements wasn't fulfilled. A rejection of "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied" from Mailgun's incoming mail servers indicates a domain or subdomain has MX records pointed toward Mailgun's but the domain does not exist within an account.

**Disclaimer I work at Mailgun

Comment: This is on point. I was getting the same "550 5.7.1" error until I realized I was using a subdomain on Mailgun. Mailgun recommends using a subdomain but I can't give a subdomain email (contact@mail.example.com) now can I?

Comment: Yeah, I always get this error and is because of the subdomain recommendation. Not sure why they recommend as it looks pretty bad..

Comment: @Totty.js So using `mg.yourdomain` as they recommend, you can only receive at `address@mg.yourdomain`? That does look bad. I set it up that way per their recommendation, but I guess it's time for a do-over. EDIT: I meant receive, not send.

Comment: @Totty.js OK, [the FAQ recommends no subdomain if you need to receive mail](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-pick-a-domain-name-for-my-mailgun-account). The warning in the UI is a bit misleading.

Comment: So in order to RECEIVE email on a domain you must have SENDING domain setup for that same domain. This is entirely counterintuitive! Mailgun should update their documentation, or better yet add automatic check inside the setup interface.

Comment: I struggled with the same issue. Receiving works for subdomains but not top-level domains. How stupid of mailgun to have that recommendation in the doc. It has been 5 years and the doc hasn't been updated!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is 6 months old, but since I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out, I will share my solution:
There is another cause of the 5.7.1 Relaying denied message: My mailgun account wasn't verified. I saw someone suggest this but I figured they just meant that I had to verify the address I was forwarding to.  Nope, when I logged in today I saw a banner at the top saying click here to resend your verification email.  I did that, it went through a text message verification process, and all immediately started working!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite a stale thread, but I also wanted to chime in here in hopes of saving folks a few hours of their life trying to solve the "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied" caper.

For me? It was what has plagued me on several occasions. I was able to verify via Gmail > 'Settings' > 'Accounts and Import' > 'Add another email address' **only after I disconnected from my software-based VPN** (Private Internet Access).

[Your sigh or wince here]

Now, go get it... make it happen.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MailGun with cPanel (for example, after following [this tutorial](https://forums.cpanel.net/resources/how-to-use-mailgun-as-a-smarthost.591/)) and you're getting the `550 5.7.1 Relaying denied` error, make sure you're using the MailGun SMTP credentials given after adding your domain (as opposed to your MailGun username and password as the documentation suggests). That was the origin of my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error code may well be that you are trying to send stuff over SMTP whereas you've indicated on the sending properties of mailgun settings for your domain that you want to use the API...